# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition'->pip install dlib error

Tags: python, cmake, python-module, face-recognition, dlib

Summary:
I am trying to run the python file which contains face_recognition. But, it is giving me ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition'.

I have tried the way to solve:

1. I looked to similar problem in StackOverflow. I got the solution to install cmake,then dlib and then face_recognition.
2. **pip install cmake** has installed the cmake module successfully.
3. But when I am installing dlib using **pip install dlib** even I tried with **pip3 install dlib**,still it is gving me error. The error is shown as :
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZTqJ.png)

4)When wrote pip install dlib. It is giving me

*
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
    You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
    are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
    that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
    development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.


    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*
```

while i am using visual studio code only for development. I have already installed c++ in vs code(gcc compiler).

It is important to be solved, because:

1)**Without this face_recognition module is not workin and I am not able to open the project as working file.**

Feel free to ask any doubt needed to the problem. Any help will be respected.

Comment: "You must use **Visual Studio**" : Note, that Visual Studio has nothing common with Visual Studio Code which you have.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this blog to see if it works, hope this helps:
[dlib installation steps](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-install-dlib-library-for-python-in-windows-10-57348ba1117f)

From what it looks like, its an external library that is needed by Windows OS, I have faced a similar scenario where I was asked to upgrade / use this library while installing PC games.

Comment: The given medium URL is downloading the whole process, but I already have c++ in vs code.

Comment: yes , but visual studio and vscode are two different stuff.